# Use of $sum inside set - Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, operators

I have the following problem.

I want to create inside my mongodb database a new field for each documentation. This field should consist as a value the sum of two other fields of the documentation.

I tried this:

```
  db.collection('restaurants').updateMany(
    {}, { $set: 
      { allScores: {$sum: "$grades.score"} } 
    }
  )
```

but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

The dollar ($) prefixed field '$sum' in 'allScores.$sum' is not valid for storage.

Why can't I use $sum inside of $set? 
And what can I do instead?

The database I used can be found here: https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/

Thanks!

Julia

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(error, client) {

    if(error) {
        return console.log('An error occured!')
    }
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  var objectId = new ObjectID();


  db.collection('restaurants').updateMany(
    {}, { $set: 
      { allScores: {$sum: "$grades.score"} } 
    }
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What version of MongoDB are you working with? Starting with 4.2, the update command supports aggregation pipeline operators. https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/update/index.html#update-command-example-agg

Comment: Is it a one time update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to do that:

```
db.collection('restaurants').aggregate([
    {$addFields : {allScores : {$sum : "$grades.score"}}},
    {$out : "restaurants"}
])
```

What this code does:

1- Find all documents inside `restaurants`;
2- Add the field `allScores` to each document;
3- Save all documents back to the collection `restaurants`;

Comment: Unfortunatly, this isn't working. When I refresh Robo 3T, no field is added to all my documents...

Comment: that's strange. I used Robo 3T to test it and it created the field `allScores` successfully. You want that new field in document root, right?

Comment: I need to add .toArray() to the aggregation, then it works... Do you have a glue why?

Comment: Could you post here the exact query you are using, please?